# Jaspersoft, How to return from the page you drilled down in a report?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a long table the spans multiple pages and in it I have a column with a hyperlink to a drilldown report.
The hyperlink is self and it replaces the current report.
How can I return back to the original report from the exact point I left it? (same page, same filter, and same order)

Answer (score 0):

There shall be "back" button on the top of drill down. It is native functionality of jasperserver. At least it is in version of jasper reports which we use.

hope this help:)